# Is it true that for every $x,y\in O, x\neq y,$ there exists an infinite compact subset $K$ of $O$ such that $x,y\in K?$

Tags: general-topology

> **Question**: Let $n\in\mathbb{N}.$ 
>   Suppose that $O\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is an open connected subset. 
>   Is it true that for every $x,y\in O, x\neq y,$ there exists an infinite compact subset $K$ of $O$ such that $x,y\in K?$

My attempt: Since $x\neq y,$ by Hausdorfness of $\mathbb{R}^n,$ there exist two disjoint open neighbourhoods $U$ and $V$ of $x$ and $y$ respectively.
We can assume both $U$ and $V$ are bounded. 
Then there exists closed subsets $A\subseteq U$ and $B\subseteq V$ that contain $x$ and $y$ respectively.
Let $K = A\cup B.$
Then $K$ is a compact subset of $O$ such that $x,y\in K.$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Did you leave a condition off your statement of the problem? Seems to me that $\{x,y\}$ is compact & contains both.

Comment: @Lubin I have added the condition that $K$ must be infinite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $O$ is connected, for any $x,y \in O$, we can find a path $\gamma : [0,1] \to O$ that is continuos from $x$ to $y$, and the image of this path contains both $x$ and $y$, which is compact since $[0,1]$ is compact and $\gamma$ is continuos.

Hence take $K := \gamma ([0,1])$.

---

About your proof, I think it is quite OK.

Actually, the question would be much more interesting if it was asking a compact and *connected* subset $K$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Yes. I am interested in your second question. But I have no idea how to prove it. Any hint?

Comment: @Idonknow If you're talking about K being also _connected_, the set $K$ that I have given is already connected since $[0,1]$ is connected and $\gamma$ is continuous.

Comment: Have you studied continuos function in a topological space ?

Comment: Yes, you are right, as continuity preserves connectedness.

Comment: @Idonknow if you are satisfied with the answer, please consider accepting it as an answer by clicking the "tick" sign that is on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Too many examples to count. Since $O$ is open and $x\in O$, there is $\varepsilon>0$ such that the ball $B(x,\varepsilon)$ of radius $\varepsilon$ centered at $x$ is contained in $O$. Now take the closure of $B(x,\varepsilon/2)$, also contained in$O$, and compact, since closed and bounded. Finally, take $B(x,\varepsilon/2)\cup\{y\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any typo?

Simply let $K=\{x,y\}$. Then $K$ is a compact subset of $O$ and $x,y\in K$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I added the condition that $K$ must be infinite.